# Firebase -Can Shard Data be shared between multiple Realtime Databases

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the Realtime Database it says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding) that if you want to scale beyond 200,000 simultaneous connections that you can create/`shard` another database. It also says:

> Each query only runs against a single database instance. Realtime
>   Database doesn't support queries across database instances.
>
> No sharing or duplication of data across database instances (or
>   minimal sharing or duplication).
>
> Each app instance only connects to one database at any given moment.

Let's say in first database I have a `Posts` ref, a `Users` ref, and a `Search Posts` ref with 100K user objects, 200K post objects, and 200K search objects. I now decide to create/`shard` another database with the same exact refs.

**When the next x amount of users signs up, if their User, Post, and Search Posts refs are in the new `shard` database, does that mean that they won't be able to access users or search those user's posts from the first database? Also vice versa the users from the first database won't be able to have access to users or their posts in the second database?**

Comment: The question asks about Sharding which is mostly related to simultaneous connections. Do you have a situation where you have 200,000 live *connections*? The general thought is to group your data - in other words if you have Posts, Users and you run queries against Posts and then at another time time run queries against Users, put posts in one database instance and Users in another. In other words, don't put users on multiple databases.

Comment: I don’t have 200k live connections but I was thinking about learning the FireStore for my next app. The big draw is multi search queries and it automatically scales. However I’m very comfortable with RTD but I hate the fact that I have to use Algolia for multi queries . That being said with RTD I thought once you build the first database, if you add a second one with the same rules and structure, when users sign up the RTD itself decides where to add them. How can you add users in one db, posts in another, and search posts in another. Seems like overkill because you might only get 10 users.

Comment: Again, the point of sharding is to load balance your *connections* and is not related to quantity of data. The RTDB makes no decisions about where data is stored, you do. One server would contain users, another would contain posts. You would run user queries against the server with users and posts queries against the serve with posts. All you're doing is pointing your app toward the server you want to query before running the query. In other words, there would be no reason to add users to server 1 and then add more users to server 2 as the quantity of data doesn't matter.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, what you just explained I’ve never seen explained anywhere else. Everything basically said you can add another database. Thanks for the info. I’m going to start on it towards the end of next week and if I have any questions post them. Not sure if you have the time but FB blog post would be good. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of sharding is to load balance your connections and is not related to quantity of data.

The RTDB makes no decisions about where data is stored, you do. One server would contain users, another would contain posts.

You would run user queries against the server with users and posts queries against the serve with posts.

All you're doing is pointing your app toward the server you want to query before running the query.

In other words, there would be no reason to add users to server 1 and then add more users to server 2 as the quantity of data doesn't matter.